# Ordered JavaScript File Loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I need to dynamically load several JavaScript file assets in a very specific order after a page has loaded. I'm trying to use `onload`, but this seems to fire before the asset has fully loaded. How should I adjust the below script to fire a proper callback to load the next script?

*Note: Only needs to work in the latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE9.*

```
function loadAssets() {
    // Setup script
    var scriptJS = document.createElement('script');
    scriptJS.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptJS.src = objectUrl;

    scriptJS.onload = loadAssetsNext();

    // Begin insertion
    var headerJS = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD');
    headerJS[0].appendChild(scriptJS);
},
function loadAssetsNext() {
    // Increment object counter
    objectsCount++;
    
    // Test to see if you should call another item
    if ((objectsCount) < objects.length) {
        // Setup script
        var scriptJS = document.createElement('script');
        scriptJS.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptJS.src = nextObjectUrl;
        
        // Declare callback to fire after script has fully loaded
        scriptJS.onload = loadAssetsNext();
    
        // Begin insertion
        var headerJS = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD');
        headerJS[0].appendChild(scriptJS);
    }
}
```

What I need is something like `scriptJS.fullyLoaded = doStuff`. Have no clue where to go from here though.

PS: jQuery is not an option or another library. You should be able to do this by slightly modifying the above script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your onload event is firing immediately is that you are calling it, not assigning it.

```
scriptJS.onload = loadAssetsNext();
```

This just assigns the returned value from the call to `loadAssetsNext` to the property `onload` of the `scriptJS` object. What you are intending to do is:

```
scriptJS.onload = loadAssetsNext;
```

*That* sets the `onload` handler to be the `loadAssests` function. This should take care of your issues.

Comment: Now that I've read the answer, I see what I wrote down incorrectly. So now the workflow is like this: scripts' onload handler is actually our function. Then, we load it and when we append it, the onload fires and loads the next script? Correct?

Comment: @zladuric Close; We create the element, assign the onload handler, append it to the DOM, when it is finished loading, it fires its onload handler, which starts the process again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `scriptJS.onload = loadAssetsNext();` is placed before   `headerJS[0].appendChild(scriptJS);`
That means that your scripts would load and get appended to the page like this:

load script 1

  load script 2

    load script 3

    ...

    append script 3

  append script 2

append script 1

So I think you should just reorder your script a little bit.

Comment: -1 You seem to think that `append` means prepend~ it does not. Additionally, adding an `onload` handler _after_ attaching an element to the DOM is not a recipe for success.

Comment: That's why I added the "I think" disclaimer :)  So, help me out on this: scriptJS.onload - part of the code (call to next) is executed when the current scriptJS is loaded? The browser fetches the source and starts fetching the next? And after all of it is done, it does appendChild for all those script tags?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the first part of your answer, I thought that you thought that it was attaching an onload handler; when you were in fact correctly parsing script execution as resulting in reverse ordered script appending. My down vote is locked unless your answer is edited =(, I'll gladly remove it if you wouldn't mind editing your response.